# Assign randomly chosen, but matching parameters for connected OMNeT++ gates?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I'm developing a network model in OMNeT++ in which I have introduced a custom channel type to represent links in my network. For one property of this channel type's instances, I'd like to assign a random parameter. However, the random number should be the same for connected gates.

My node definition has the following gates definition:

```
simple GridAgent
{
    /* ... other paramters/definitions omitted ... */
    gates:
        inout agentConnections[];
}
```

In my network configuration, I connect nodes using the simple `<-->` syntax, e.g.:

```
someSwitchyard.agentConnections++ <--> AgentConnectionChannel <--> someWindfarm.agentConnections++;
```

Now, this AgentConnectionChannel has a property called *impedance*, which I'd like to randomly assign. This *impedance* property should be the same for both A -> B and B -> A. I have tried to add `{ impedance = default(unitform(1, 10)) }` to the network definition, as well as putting `**.agentConnections$o[*].channel.impedance = uniform(1, 10)` into `omnetpp.ini`. In both cases, however, A -> B has a different value assigned than B -> A.

As indicated on the [OMNet++ mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/hesVQSSCjjw), this happens because the `<-->` syntax is actually a shorthand for creating two distinct connections, hence two drawings from the random number distribution happen.

How can I assign a random parameter to a connection's property *and* have the same value for both directions of two connected gates? Is there a way to do this in the `omnetpp.ini` file, or do I need to create a script in, e.g., Perl, Ruby, or Python to generate the `omnetpp.ini` for my runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple solution of your problem, and it could not be resolved manipulating `omnetpp.ini` file merely. 
I propose manual rewriting a parameter value for the second direction. It requires preparing a C++ class for a channel (which you have probably done).
Assuming that your channel definition in NED is following:

```
channel AgentConnectionChannel extends ned.DatarateChannel {
  @class(AgentConnectionChannel);
  double impedance;
}
```

and in `omnetpp.ini` you has:

```
**.agentConnections$o[*].channel.impedance = uniform(1, 10)
```

you should prepare `C++` class `AgentConnectionChannel`:

```
class AgentConnectionChannel: public cDatarateChannel {
public:
    AgentConnectionChannel() : parAlreadyRewritten(false) {}
    void setParAlreadyRewritten() {parAlreadyRewritten=true;}

protected:
    virtual void initialize();

private:
    bool parAlreadyRewritten;

private:
    double impedance;
};

Define_Channel(AgentConnectionChannel);

void AgentConnectionChannel::initialize() {
    if (parAlreadyRewritten == false) {
        parAlreadyRewritten = true; 
        cGate * srcOut = this->getSourceGate();
        cModule *owner = srcOut->getOwnerModule();
        int index = srcOut->isVector() ? srcOut->getIndex() : -1;
        cGate *srcIn = owner->gateHalf(srcOut->getBaseName(), cGate::INPUT,
                index);
        cChannel * channel = srcIn->findIncomingTransmissionChannel();
        AgentConnectionChannel * reverseChan =
                dynamic_cast<AgentConnectionChannel*>(channel);
        if (reverseChan) {
            reverseChan->setParAlreadyRewritten();
            // assigning a value from forward direction channel
            reverseChan->par("impedance") = this->par("impedance");
        }
    }

    // and now read a parameter as usual
    impedance = par("impedance").doubleValue();
    EV << getFullPath() << ", impedance=" << impedance << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure your solution works if both channels are created in parallel (but I also don't know whether OMNeT++ optimizes that way). I could imagine (but haven't tested) that a simpler work-around is possible using a [named iteration variable](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec343), by basically using a temporary setting: `.myParameter=${par=uniform(1,10)}` and then `.impendance=${$par}`, or alternatively loading the parameter from elsewhere, instead of writing to the reverse channel from the actual channel.

Comment: @Rens van der Heijden: `OMNeT++` uses one thread so there is no possibility of parallel creating of two modules, channels, etc. Using a temporary variable is not possible because of textual substitution. As a consequence in your example: `**.impedance=${$par}` results in `**.impedance=uniform(1,10)`, so a new random value is assigned.

Comment: @JerzyD. Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I need. And thanks also for the explanation on why it isn't directly possible in `omnetpp.ini` - I would have always wondered whether I'm just using a "hack."